# GameScene.sks and GameScene.swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Having issues with the GameScene.sks and GameScene.swift. I was attempting to add a title screen to my project and it went downhill from there. The title screen works fine but the issue is when I edit the Gameviewcontroller.swift.

[This is how I want it to look, mind you I deleted the gamescene.sks at the start of the project but I realized you need sks file when you switch between scenes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrdTo.png)

[This is how it ends up looking when I re-add the gamescene.sks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33hfL.png)

Here is the GameViewController.Swift to the working file before added the TitleScreen

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Here it is after changing the view to load up the title screen first:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

         if let scene = titleScreen(fileNamed: "titleScreen") {

                //Configure view 
                let skView = self.view as! SKView
                skView.showsFPS = true
                skView.showsNodeCount = true
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
               // scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                scene.size = self.view.frame.size
                // Present the scene
                skView.presentScene(scene)


            }


    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Inspect anchor point in both ways. Use same scene scale mode. Check if positions of nodes are the same. If all of those matches, then you will have to see the same results. Also scene and a view size is a different thing so pay attention to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be that you aren't configuring your GameScene instance...

`scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill` is only called in your gameviewcontroller... yes?

that means only there is your FIRST scene getting configured.

In your title scene, wherever it is that you are `presentScene`, you need to configure your next scene...

```
func configureScene(_ scene: SKScene) -> SKScene {
  scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
  scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5) // Or whatever you want..
  scene.size = UIWindow().frame.size // Or whatever size you want.
  return scene
}
```

Implement:

```
// Where self is an SKScene...
self.presentScene(configureScene(desiredScene))
```

Also as WW said, frame and scene sizes are different, and will affect how everything looks.